# Nothing rendered into outlet

Tags: ember.js

I am manually rendering some outlets:

```
Dashboard.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate : function ( ) {
        this.render('index');
        this.render('disposition-legend', {outlet : 'dispositionLegend'} );
    },
});
```

The templates:

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      {{outlet}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      <div class="container">
        {{outlet dispositionLegend}}
      </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="disposition-legend">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 well">Legend:&nbsp;
          {{#each controller.content}}
            <span class="label" style="background-color:{{unbound color}};">{{label}}</span>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>
```

Ember says that is is indeed rendering the outlet:

```
Rendering index with default view <Ember._MetamorphView:ember320> Object {fullName: "view:index"}
Rendering disposition-legend with <Dashboard.DispositionLegendView:ember328> Object {fullName: "view:disposition-legend"}
```

There are no error messages, but neither view `ember320` nor view `ember328` are in the DOM. The only view present in the DOM is `ember299`, related to the `application` template.

Why could that be?

(I am running `ember-1.4.0`)

Answer (score 2):

The `IndexRoute` is trying to render into `application` template, but you want to render into `index`, so you need to pass the `into: 'index'` option.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate : function ( ) {
        this.render('index');
        this.render('disposition-legend', {outlet : 'dispositionLegend', into: 'index'} );
    },
});
```

Comment: YES! There is one thing that I do not understand yet: why is there no DOM element for the index template? First, I am telling it to render *and* it is confirming that it will render. Second, disposition-legend is a child of index. How can it be that disposition-legend is there, but index is not there?